# Infinite monkey theorem: Average times a given string appears in $n$ typed characters?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to get my head around how to think about the following case of the infinite monkey theorem.

> How many times on average does a given string appear in $n$ characters typed by the monkey?

The monkey types one randomly selected character at a time.

The set of characters is bounded, say e.g. the lowercase alphabet, or a set of M characters.

I'm thinking that it's probably, for some example string e.g. "math", found by looking at the probability of "m" then "m being followed by a", then "ma being followed by t" and so on. Is this it? What are the probabilities?

Then perhaps "wrapping it up" by considering the probability of "the given string starts at index i of n typed characters"

Comment: You will need to be clearer on how the monkeys act.  These particular monkeys may have a particular fondness for the return carriage since it makes the bell sound and for causing a mess and it might be an incredibly long time before anything of interest gets typed.  You may be interested in reading about [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).  Perhaps what you are hoping for is information about if each key has equal chance of being struck at which point consider a normal number in base $26$ (or higher if you want to allow punctuation or spaces).

Comment: There's just one monkey.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to the point I was making.  Without information on how the monkey (singular if you insist, but it doesn't change anything) acts, then the answer could be anywhere from zero times (he never types it) to $\lfloor \frac{n}{l}\rfloor$ where $l$ is the length of the string (in the case that the string is not cyclic).  As I suggested could be the case, the monkey in question might type "randomly" yet will hit things in such a pattern as to have zero chance of typing the target word.

Comment: Take for example an ape with large thick fingers that whenever he touches the keyboard winds up pressing multiple adjacent buttons.  Could such an ape ever succesfully type "math"?  No.

Comment: It types (i.e. selects) the characters randomly, one at a time.

Comment: I believe here at least a partial solution is given: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=25434

Comment: The problem you linked gives additional details (each key is pressed **independently and uniformly at random**).  This information is necessary.  The linked page in fact gives a *full* solution in the seventh post.   As it suggests, you should consider an indicator random variable $X_i$ whose value is $1$ if the target string appears at index $i$.  The sum of these random variables is exactly the random variable which counts how many times the string appears.  Now, using linearity of expectation you get your result.